# Open look up automatically on tab out in Maximo 7.6

Tags: maximo

Is there a way to show up look up automatically when some words are typed in on the field and tab out in Maximo? At the moment a magnifying glass comes up which on click displays the look up however we would like to skip the magnifying glass and directly display the look up.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Always Synchronous** box in the field's advanced properties (in `Application Designer`) as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Type Ahead feature. It will load the the fields and rows you specify to the browser cache. It has got some quirks, but it useful in some situations where the lookup has a limited set (under 100?) to choose from.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Maximo%20Asset%20Management/page/Configuring%20the%20type-ahead%20feature